# Community Promotion Ads - 2015

Tags: discussion, community-ads

The dawn of a new year, 2015, now approaches, or has already approached, either way it means that it is now time to reset our Community Promotion Ads!

#### What are Community Promotion Ads?

Community Promotion Ads are community-vetted advertisements that will show up on the main site, in the right sidebar. The purpose of this question is the vetting process. Images of the advertisements are provided, and community voting will enable the advertisements to be shown.

#### Why do we have Community Promotion Ads?

This is a method for the community to control what gets promoted to visitors on the site. For example, you might promote the following things:

- interesting unix and linux related open source apps
- the site's twitter account
- script packs or power tools
- cool events or conferences
- anything else your community would genuinely be interested in

The goal is for future visitors to find out about *the stuff your community deems important*. This also serves as a way to promote information and resources that are *relevant to your own community's interests*, both for those already in the community and those yet to join.

#### Why do we reset the ads every year?

Some services will maintain usefulness over the years, while other things will wane to allow for new faces to show up. Resetting the ads every year helps accommodate this, and allows old ads that have served their purpose to be cycled out for fresher ads for newer things. This helps keep the material in the ads relevant to not just the subject matter of the community, but to the current status of the community. We reset the ads once a year, every December.

The community promotion ads have no restrictions against reposting an ad from a previous cycle. If a particular service or ad is very valuable to the community and will continue to be so, it is a good idea to repost it. It may be helpful to give it a new face in the process, so as to prevent the imagery of the ad from getting stale after a year of exposure.

#### How does it work?

The answers you post to this question *must* conform to the following rules, or they will be ignored.

1. All answers should be in the exact form of:

   ```
   [![Tagline to show on mouseover][1]][2]

      [1]: http://image-url
      [2]: http://clickthrough-url
   ```

   Please **do not add anything else to the body of the post**. If you want to discuss something, do it in the comments.
2. The question must always be tagged with the magic [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads) tag. In addition to enabling the functionality of the advertisements, this tag also pre-fills the answer form with the above required form.

#### Image requirements

- The image that you create must be **220 x 250 pixels**
- Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
- Must be GIF or PNG
- No animated GIFs
- Absolute limit on file size of 150 KB

#### Score Threshold

There is a **minimum score threshold** an answer must meet (currently **6**) before it will be shown on the main site.

You can check out the ads that have met the threshold with basic click stats [here](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/ads/display/3311).

Comment: It would be nice if the ratio of the ads that we want to see (those below) to those that have no interest to the community at all (most of the others) was adjusted in our favour: currently it seems about 1:10...

Comment: I like ads that actually look like ads and aren't just a random logo. A logo by itself would look out of place to me.

Answer (score 26):

[image: Zsh: the last word in Unix shells]

Comment: Thanks to [Stéphane Chazelas](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/a/2568)

Answer (score 26):

[image: GNU Parallel - for people who live life in the parallel lane]

Comment: Just realised those stripes actually _are_ parallel (though my brain clearly thinks they're not).

Comment: GNU Parallel cannot take credit for that idea: It is the Cafe Wall Illusion: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caf%C3%A9_wall_illusion

Answer (score 25):

[image: Vim: the power tool for everyone]

Comment: The "m" letter is ugly.

Comment: @DeerHunter Bram doesn't strike me as someone who obsesses over branding and logos...

Comment: @jasonwryan think it's worth posting one for [vi.se]? (an image from http://meta.vi.stackexchange.com/q/1215/205, maybe)

Comment: @muru excellent idea!

Comment: @jasonwryan [done](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/a/3666/70524). So that's three Vim-related posts here! :D

Answer (score 25):

[image: GNU's Not Unix!]

Answer (score 24):

[image: A convenient and expressive programming language]

Answer (score 17):

[image: The FreeBSD Project]

Answer (score 16):

[image: Operating systems principles and design — Computer Science Stack Exchange]

Comment: Thanks to [Wandering Logic](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/799/advertising-computer-science-stack-exchange-on-other-se-sites/962#962)

Answer (score 14):

[image: Arch wiki]

Answer (score 11):

[image: Fedora is now more focused — Less setup, more innovation. Choose a flavor of Fedora streamlined for your needs, and get to work right away.]

Answer (score 11):

[image: Software Recommendations]

Comment: Shouldn't this link to the [linux](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/tags/linux) tag?

Comment: @Gilles Why not! We receive very little AIX/Solaris/HPUX/etc questions in comparison with Linux questions.

Answer (score 11):

[image: Vi and Vim Stack Exchange]

Answer (score 9):

[image: KDE Community]

Answer (score 7):

[image: A keyboard-driven, minimalist web browser]

Answer (score 7):

[image: Emacs text editor]

Comment: Needs some text.

Comment: A 1px border is needed according to the rules.

Answer (score 7):

[image: Fedora Magazine: News and articles for users and contributors]

Answer (score 7):

[See all questions with active bounties http://stack-exchange-dynamic-ads.herokuapp.com/unix.stackexchange.com/bounty.png](https://unix.stackexchange.com/?tab=featured)

Comment: This is an adaption of [Community Promotion Ads - 2015](http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/12383).

Comment: "The image that you create must be 220 x 250 pixels"...

Comment: @jasonwryan: Not really. See [Community Promotion Ads - 2014](http://meta.apple.stackexchange.com/a/1884).

Answer (score 6):

[image: software that sucks less...]

Answer (score 5):

[image: GNU Parallel - for people who live life in the parallel lane]

Comment: More colourful background.

Comment: I think it distracts from the mind-melting optical illusion.

Answer (score 5):

[image: vim's rebirth for the 21st century]

Answer (score 0):

[image: Fedora Workstation: This is the Linux workstation you've been waiting for.]

Answer (score 0):

[image: Fedora Cloud: Lean. Powerful. Everycloud ready.]

Answer (score 0):

[image: Fedora Server: The latest technology. A stable foundation.]

Answer (score -4):

[image: Check out the Area 51 Remote Sensing Proposal]

Answer (score -5):

[image: Follow us on Twitter]

Comment: [:)](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3311/community-promotion-ads-2015/3345#comment4925_3312)

Comment: Nice joke and all, but this gives the impression that U&L, as in *the site*, is more negative than Server Fault.

Comment: I saw the link and I *still* don't get the joke...anyone care to explain?

Comment: @Wildcard Every time the next year's Community Ads question is posted, it comes with a sample answer (an ad for the site's Twitter account). For some reason, it always gets heavily downvoted on some sites, and we seem to consistently vote it even lower than Server Fault, even though we're a *waaaaay* smaller site. This answer is just my silly implementation of Michael's comment, which implied we should treat that "negativity" as an achievement and show it off.

Answer (score -18):

[image: Follow us on Twitter]

Comment: This is a demonstration post to indicate how this should look when an ad is posted. It also doubles as your twitter ad, but it's up to you if you wish to promote it by voting. Which you probably won't. -21 is currently the network record for poorest reception - you even outvoted Server Fault.

Comment: Can you make a version that replaces "Follow us on twitter!" with "More negative than Server Fault!"?

Comment: See me next year and I'll see what I can do.

Comment: @MichaelMrozek [SF is already well below us](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/6841) (so there are people who vote on SF after all!), but this year [Math](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/19015) is expressing [unprecedented](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/11921) hatred of their Twitter bot!

Comment: @MichaelMrozek - http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/a/3345/52956...